# Regex match all strings containing a given series of letters or digits

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a search box and i need to grab the value of this search and match all DIV which data-* value is starting with the search value.

Cases:

Search value: `201`

Should **match**: `data-year="2011"`, `data-year="2012"`, `data-year="2013"`

Should **fail**: `data-year="2009"`, `data-year="2001"`

This is what i come up with so far:

```
\\b(?=\\w*[" + token + "])\\w+\\b
```

`token` is a dynamic value from the search box. Therefore i need to use RegExp

This is working but it match all the value which contain 2 or 0 or 1 (for my understanding). so 2009 is valid match as well. :/

I also try to add the caret at the beginning in order to match the characthers just at the beginning of the world but clearly i'm missing something here:

```
^\\b(?=\\w*[" + token + "])\\w+\\b
```

The whole code is:

```
var token = '200'; // should fail
var tokenTwo = '201'; // shoudl work
var dataAtt = $('#div').data('year').toString(); 
var regexExpression ="^\\b(?=\\w*\\d*[" + token + "])\\w+\\d+\\b";
var regEXPRES = "^.*" + token + ".*$";
var regex = new RegExp(regexExpression, "i");

if( dataAtt.match(regex) ){
 console.log(dataAtt);

alert('yey!!!');
} else {
    alert('nope!! )')
}
```

and here is the JsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tk5m8coo/

p.s. I shouldn't have any cases where `token` is precede or follow by other characters, but if anyone as idea how to check also this, would be great. Just in case of any typo like s2015.

Comment: Don’t mess around with this using RegEx – create the proper attribute selector from your input, then it is one single jQuery call that gets you all relevant elements. https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

Comment: I agree with using an attribute selector, but there is really no need to use jQuery for something every modern browser can do... e.g. `document.querySelectorAll('[data-year^="201"]')`

Comment: thank you for your answer. Why do you think is better to use the attribute selector?

Comment: Also @CBroe how can i use this with the jQuery this?
Something like that:  jQuery(this + '[data-year^="' + token + '"]') is not accepted

Comment: @hsan: You’re right, this doesn’t require jQuery. I mentioned it because I though the question was tagged jquery, but that was just a mistake on my part it seems.

Comment: _“Something like that: jQuery(this + '[data-year^="' + token + '"]') is not accepted”_ – well that doesn’t even begin to make sense. `this` is an object, trying to concatenate string to it makes no sense. What do you think you need this for here anyway – don’t you want to find _all_ matching elements? (If you only want to search within a certain container element - then pass that as the _context_ parameter.)

Comment: thank you for your nice words, i know it doesn't make sense, i just wanted to show what i mean... anyway i'm looping a list of divs so i want to check if they have same data-year as the search value. Of;course i can do without check (just match all elements with data-year"200" but i find more safe to do a check).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that you're putting your search value inside a character class when you enclose your regex by wrapping around `[...]`.

You also don't need a lookahead. You can just use:

```
var regex = new RegExp("\\b\\w*" + value + "\\w*\\b");
```

To make sure search value is matched within a full word. (`\w` includes digits also so no need to use `\d`).

Full code:

```
var value = '20'; //token
var html = $("#div").html(); //data.()
var dataAtt = $('#div').data('year').toString(); 

var regex = new RegExp("\\b\\w*" + value + "\\w*\\b");

if( dataAtt.match(regex) ){
   console.log(dataAtt + " matched");
} else {
   console.log('nope')
}
```

[Updated JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tk5m8coo/1/)

Comment: :) Thanks you! Also for the explanation. I was actually wondering if i could get rid of the \d.

Comment: It doesn't seems to work when there are many divs :/
http://jsfiddle.net/tk5m8coo/5/

Comment: That's not correct because `dataAtt` is `2015` and within a `foreach` loop you're repeatedly matching search value `200` against `2015`

Comment: oh right! I actually have already correct my app like this yesterday, my bad! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use `indexOf()`:

```js
var value = '20';
var html = $("#div").html();
var dataAtt = $('#div').data('year').toString(); 


if( dataAtt.indexOf(value) >= 0 ){
     console.log('yey!!!');
} else {
    console.log('nein!! )')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id ="div" data-year="2015">
    what bozo where 2015
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is using a character class which will match any of the characters inside the square brackets. Remove the square brackets:

```
^\\b(?=\\w*" + token + ".*)\\w+\\b
```

Comment: thank you Dan, your solution also works pretty great. I will accept as answer the anubhava's one just because he was faster

Comment: @GiorgiaSambrotta no problem, anubhava's is also more complete.